# Can't use PySpark DF cached in Google Colab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I realized that using any method (like show() or any other) after caching a PySpark Dataframe within Google Colab environment I got this error:

like:

```
df.show(5)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_26/1842469281.py in <module>
----> 1 df.show(5)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    604 
    605         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 606             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    607         else:
    608             try:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1318             proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1319 
-> 1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in send_command(self, command, retry, binary)
   1034          if `binary` is `True`.
   1035         """
-> 1036         connection = self._get_connection()
   1037         try:
   1038             response = connection.send_command(command)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py in _get_connection(self)
    282 
    283         if connection is None or connection.socket is None:
--> 284             connection = self._create_new_connection()
    285         return connection
    286 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py in _create_new_connection(self)
    289             self.java_parameters, self.python_parameters,
    290             self.gateway_property, self)
--> 291         connection.connect_to_java_server()
    292         self.set_thread_connection(connection)
    293         return connection

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/clientserver.py in connect_to_java_server(self)
    436                 self.socket = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(
    437                     self.socket, server_hostname=self.java_address)
--> 438             self.socket.connect((self.java_address, self.java_port))
    439             self.stream = self.socket.makefile("rb")
    440             self.is_connected = True

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am new to Spark/PySpark and can't understand why this happens. Is it because I'm not using a proper cluster?

Comment: Can you add the code that reproduce this error ?

Comment: I simply read some CSVs files in one DF, something like this:

`spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("trips_data").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet(f"path/to/file.parquet").cache()`

then if I try a `show(5)` it raises the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's not enough space to cache the dataframe in memory! It's an rdd long linkage error due to memory overflow in JVM.

I'm not sure if you can increase memory in google collab, so either use smaller files in google collab, or test locally if you have enough memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll keep an eye on this kind of behavior. Nonetheless, it's odd because supposedly colab has 30gb of RAM and my files had about 10gb...

Comment: It's because parquet files are compressed files, so when loaded to memory they will be decompressed which will lead to significant size increase.